# Is there a method/web server to generate Position-specific scoring matrix (PSSM) for nucleotide sequences (DNA/RNA)?

Tags: rna, pssm, dna

Just like, PSI-BLAST is avaialble to generate a PSSM matrix for peptides, is there a web server where we can generate PSSM for DNA/RNA? I want to find homologous sequences to a given RNA sequence.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what your final objective is here. How would you use this matrix? To do what? The choice of tool and approach will depend on what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Not a web server, but a method is available in biopython to do produce PSSMs. I've used it a number of times and it works well as far as I can tell.

Comment: thanks, but I believe the biopython method caters to DNA sequences only. But that might help as well.

Comment: @terdon sure I have edited.

Comment: Is this RNA translated? If so, it would make more sense to search using tools like tblastn.  Does it have a specific structure? If so, you can use tools that look for similar structures. Do you have multiple homologs of it? Aligned? Or are you starting from a single sequences? What does the RNA do? Depending on what it does, you would focus on different features when looking for homologs.